# Projection Queries: How to load raw String using JPA for new Entity in AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, entity, google-cloud-datastore

How do I load a list of Strings for a brand new, empty, non-existent table in AppEngine? I tried to follow this example:

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Projection_of_Path_Expressions_

but it gives me an error:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class AdminUser for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification
>
> Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class AdminUser for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification

Here is the code:

```
public java.util.List<String> getAdmin() {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        TypedQuery<String> tq = em.createQuery("select au.email from AdminUser as au", String.class);
        return tq.getResultList();  ///// <=== EXCEPTION
```

I don't actually want to use an AdminUser class. I only want the single column of Strings. It is not obvious how to create a new empty table on AppEngine.

Comment: If you don't want to create an AdminUser class then don't refer to one. Start by reading the JPA spec and the part about JPQL, and refer to the classes you actually have. Why not mention what class you do have? and what field of that class you want to select?

Comment: @DataNucleus That is very unhelpful. Did you look at the example link?

Comment: It is the role of the reader to make comments so that the person asking the question actually presents an intelligible question; which this currently isn't. If you are using JPA you have some classes, some metadata, some persistence code, some query. You want to "load a list of Strings" ... where is it ? You dont say, but go on about creating an "empty table". Clarify your question is the first step

Comment: @DataNucleus Sorry I can't help you with reading comprehension. My question is sufficient. Everything you question is present.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AppEngine does not support JPA raw primitive queries as in the example link. I had to use the DatastoreService API directly. Here is what I tried. Needs some cleaning as many of the things did not work, but this did.

```
    public java.util.List<String> getAdmin() {
        log.info("getAdmin()");

        // AppEngine does not support strong consistency... will frequently return stale results. Setting read policy won't work.
        // Construct a read policy for strong consistency
        ReadPolicy policy = new ReadPolicy(ReadPolicy.Consistency.STRONG);
        // Set the read policy
        DatastoreServiceConfig consistentConfig = DatastoreServiceConfig.Builder.withReadPolicy(policy);
        // Get Datastore service with the given configuration
        DatastoreService datastoreService =  DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(consistentConfig);

        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query query  = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("AdminUser");
//      DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        java.util.List<Entity> events = datastoreService.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Entity entity: events) {
            String s = entity.getProperty("email").toString();
            al.add(s);
        }
        if(true) return al; 


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
        try {
            TypedQuery<String> tq = em.createQuery("select au.email from AdminUser as au", String.class);
            return tq.getResultList();
        } catch (ClassNotResolvedException | javax.persistence.PersistenceException cnre) {
            // catch the exception because AppEngine DataStore has no way to create a new empty Entity table.
            log.warning("AdminUser entity does not exist or is empty.");
            return new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        } finally {
            em.close(); 
        }

//      log.info("getAdmin(): al.size(): " + al.size());
    }


    public void setAdmin(java.util.List<String> admin) {
        log.info("setAdmin(), admin.size():"+admin.size());

        // delete all AdminUsers
        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query query  = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("AdminUser");
        DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        java.util.List<Entity> events = datastoreService.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
        for(Entity entity: events) {
            datastoreService.delete(entity.getKey());
        }


//      EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
//      Query q = em.createQuery("delete from AdminUser");
//      q.executeUpdate();


//      DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        for (String s: admin) {
            log.info("creating AdminUser Entity...");
            Entity e = new Entity("AdminUser");
            e.setProperty("email", s);
            datastoreService.put(e);    
        }
        // Must wait for Datastore to actually write records. Ignores consistency even with strong consistency set.
        // this doesn't even work sometimes...
        //try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

//      EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
//      for (String s: admin) {
//          Entity e = new Entity("AdminUser");
//          e.setProperty("email", s);
//          em.persist(e);
//      }
//      em.close();

    } // setAdmin()
```

Answer (score 1):

GAE Datastore is a schemaless NoSQL database. There are no tables. Only entities that must have a kind, an id and can have an arbitrary set of properties.

You can use [Datastore via JPA API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview), to give you nice typed Java classes instead of [low-level untyped entities](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities).

Comment: Yes I've read that, but it doesn't say how to create an empty table/Entity. I will need to read from the table first before I can create a row to insert. Normally for web application, you can go into the database directly and create a table. Are you saying, indirectly, that Google AppEngine doesn't support creating tables/Entities to bootstrap a web application?

Comment: Exactly, there is no schema, so there are no tables to define.

Comment: Wow that seems like a gaping hole in Google's design. You are saying that one must comment out the code which reads in order to first create a single unused object, then un-comment and redeploy to be able to read the table, and then always ignore the placeholder entity because it will throw an exception if the Entity list is empty. That sounds very, very messy.

Comment: There are more then 100k apps on GAE, so they must be doing something right, right?

Comment: Also, it seems that your JPA exception is due to you not having `AdminUser` class defined. This has nothing to do with AppEngine or it's datastore. JPA is a helper library mapping data from database to Java classes.

Comment: I had mentioned in the question I don't want to create an AdminUser class and I want just a raw list of Strings.

Comment: but don't say where those "strings" are. If they aren't in the AdminUser class (which doesn't exist apparently) then where are they?

Comment: @NeilStockton They will be in the AdminUser entity table, duh! Why do you think I am selecting from that entity table? I thought it was rather obvious, but I can see how someone might misinterpret that.

Comment: I would say the gaping hole is where your manners should be, rather than in Google's design of appengine.